# Google Drive API should open a local URL

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

i´m searching for a way, that a google drive app opens a local url from my extension.

I only know the way, that my extension redirects after opening a file with my extension to an web URL.

I need a way, to open an javascript (e.g. index.js) from the folder of my extension, that is installad on the users pc.

Does somebody knows a solution?

The background of this workaround: No private data should go to my webserver. All actions should be handled over javascript in the browser of the user.

Comment: You want to call the extension that will then call the Drive API? Also, what do you mean by local URL? Drive API only handles Drive-related files and not local files in the user's device. The only time Drive will have concern with local files is when its being uploaded.